# Angular 2 : Sorting 12hr time

Tags: angular, sorting

I am trying to sort a 12hr time array,

I have sorted 24hr time using this code

```
 this.timings.Mon.sort( function(name1, name2) {
        if ( name1.open_time_time < name2.open_time_time ){
            return -1;
        }else if( name1.open_time_time > name2.open_time_time ){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
 });
```

the issue is that I am converting the time to HH:mm using moment, and that value is been sort(it works too). but as it is converted, its can't be displayed as AM/PM using datepipe

```
  this.timings.Mon = res.timings.filter(x => x.open_time && x.close_time && x.day === 'Mon').map(function (x) {

            return { id: x.id, open_time_time: moment(moment.utc(x.open_time).toDate()).format('HH:mm'), open_time: x.open_time, close_time_time: 
moment(moment.utc(x.close_time).toDate()).format('HH:mm'), close_time: x.close_time, working: x.working };
            });
```

Sample Time listing is

04:45

09:00

15:00

21:00

21:30

(I'm Getting it in the sorted order which is in 24hr format)

**Is there any way to sort 12hr time or to covert and display the sorted 24hr date in 12hr format ?**

Answer (score 0):

Here is method which accepts timeStamp of Date which will returns you TIME in 12 HR format

```
function TimeFormat (value) {
            if (!value) { return ''; }
            var hours = new Date(value).getHours();
            var minutes = new Date(value).getMinutes();
            var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
            hours = hours % 12;
            hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
            var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
            return strTime;
        }
```

Here is [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/time-format-12hour?file=src/app/app.component.ts)